# How to read window content (using accessibilityService) and evoking UI using draw over other app permission in Android?

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

My [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362088/how-to-read-screen-content-in-android-programmatically) question about the same topic was not clear enough and was put on hold by community and later it was automatically deleted. So, I am explaining that Question in detailed manner so that community can understand and help in a better manner.

I want functionality similar to [Voodoo App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.voodoo.android&hl=en) and [MySmartPrice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MySmartPrice.MySmartPrice&hl=en) offers.

**Now what they do**

**Step 1:** When we open the Voodoo App for the first time they show a small tutorial. At the end of tutorial there is a "Activate Now" button which when pressed take us to Accessibility settings screen.

**Step 2:** In Accessibility Screen it further guides how to find and unable the Voodoo Service.

**Step 3:** When we enable it, it further ask to grant "Observe Your Action" and "Retrieve Window Content" permissions.

**Step 4:** Once we are done granting permissions on accessibility screen, and move to some shopping app or access shopping site via browser and reach product page a voodoo floating button pops up automatically.

**Step 5:** Once we click on it, it shows the price of same/related/similar products available on other apps or website so that user can check for best deal available.

Reference Screenshot of Voodoo

[image: Voodoo Screen 1]

[image: Accessibility screen]

[image: Accessibility screen 2]

[image: Permission Granting Screen]

[image: Voodoo Screen 2]

[image: Voodoo Floating Button on product page]

[image: Voodoo Results with the help of draw over other app]

Now what I want to know form community:

1. How I can show my help UI over Accessibility screen and product detail page.
2. How to detect when a product page is there on screen and to evoke my floating button.
3. How to fetch name of product shown on screen.
4. How to restrict this screen reading functionality for some apps only? (as I don't want to end up in some copyright issue)
5. Is there any tutorial which can help me out? Although I had already tried on Google for any direct tutorial and didn't got any success.

Now why I need this information:

I am planning a app for students which will help them to get there desired (or similar) book (ebook) for free if it is available on my server or on some web location which is available web. I want to restrict it the functionality to some apps only due to copyright issues on some books.

Now what I know from my study regarding this topic (but I am not sure whether I am on right track or not)

- I can take help form [Accessibility Service](http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html)
- Draw Over Other Apps. [Example 1](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/) , [Example 2](https://medium.com/@rotxed/drawing-over-other-apps-marshmallow-edition-987eff9f99a9#.u9zqsdq5s)

Comment: I am able read text from screen, but how to get exact product name only.

Comment: Problem Is solved. If any one require the solution. Please leave the comment. I'll try to post the complete anwser as soon as possible.

Comment: can you please share how you solved the problem?

Comment: @mahesh you can check my answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had tried to summarize how i was able to get thru the problem in a blog post. Anyone who needs some help can take a look into it.

[Accessibility Service to the next level](https://web.archive.org/web/20161228170758/http://axovel.com/blog/2016/05/06/taking-accessibility-service-to-next-level-android/)

My Previous answer was deleted by moderators may due to i just posted a link to blog. So i am posting my answer again with details here too.

The easiest way is provided by android itself. If you are building something on your own app this is the best and easiest possible way of doing it. You have to use “findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId
()” as explained below

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource(); 
    if (source == null) {
        return; 
    } 
    List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId = source.findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("YOUR PACKAGE NAME:id/RESOURCE ID FROM WHERE YOU WANT DATA"); 
    if (findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() > 0) {
        AccessibilityNodeInfo parent = (AccessibilityNodeInfo) findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.get(0);
        // You can also traverse the list if required data is deep in view hierarchy. 
        String requiredText = parent.getText().toString();
        Log.i("Required Text", requiredText);
    }
}
```

If you are building something on other apps and don’t know the res id. You have to build a logic with the combination of parent, child count, level on which your data is found, type of event. You have to look for a pattern in event or source or the combination of above said values to get the required data preciously. Further, you have to setup some tweak in your code to get the accurate data according to your task. Like in our task we have some regex to get precious data.

You have to take care that if the view or UI is changed or res ids are changed your current logic might fail. So, you have to keep a close look at the app on which you are building your service. Following are some example code in which we are getting data without res id that might be useful for you to understand how it will work.

To print source and event

```
@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfo source = event.getSource();
    if (source == null) {
        return;
    } 
    Log.i("Event", event.toString() + ""); 
    Log.i("Source", source.toString() + "");
}
```

To get the childcount

```
source.getChildCount();
```

If child count is >0 you might have to look into it.

**Example Code 1**

```
if (level == 0 && source.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView") && source.getText()!=null && !source.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    // here level is iteration of for loop
    String recivedText = source.getText().toString(); 
    if(source.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView") && source.getParent()!=null && source.getParent().getClassName().equals("android.widget.FrameLayout") && source.getParent().getParent()==null){ 
        return recivedText;
    }
}
```

**Example Code 2**

```
if (source.getPackageName().equals("PACKAGE NAME OF APP FOR WHICH YOUR EXPECTING EVENT")) {
    if(event.getEventType()==AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED && "COMPLETE NAME OF ACTIVITY CLASS WITH PACKAGE NAME (if you want it for some specific screen)".equals(event.getClassName())){
        if(source.getText()!=null && source.getClassName().equals("android.widget.TextView") && source.getParent()!=null && source.getParent().getClassName().equals("android.widget.RelativeLayout")&& source.getParent().getParent()!=null && source.getParent().getParent().getClassName().equals("android.widget.ScrollView") && source.getParent().getParent().getParent()!=null && source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getClassName().equals("android.support.v4.view.ViewPager")&& source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()!=null && source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getClassName().equals("android.widget.FrameLayout")&& source.getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent()==null){
        return source.getText().toString();
        }
}
```

It is bit clumsy but to get it working you have to look deep into logs to find a pattern which will take you to your required data.

**Update 20/11/2017**
Google is suspending all apps using accessibility services for things other than accessibility. I had received a email regarding the same for one of my app and other developers are also receiving same email from google ([Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/7c4go5/is_google_play_really_going_to_suspend_all_apps/)). So, I think we should look for some other way of doing things and I request you to please update it here also, if some one comes up with other implementation to achieve same behavior it would help others also.

Thanks
Umesh Chauhan

Comment: Thanks umesh your answer + Blog helped me a lot in identifying almost all the shopping apps.  I have some small doubt as of now i am registering to certain packages and i am getting the events but how do i know if the app is changed?(i:e; user pressed home button etc...) because at that time i need to remove the chat bubble ...  any idea?

Comment: Add launcher package to your accessibility service and when you receive a event from launcher simply dismiss the overlay if it is in window.

Comment: Thank you.  I have a couple of questions would you mind if I can contact you may be via email?

Comment: One of those questions is how to remove bubble when user came back from product detail page? Ex: I went to snapdeal product detail page I found name and price showed the bubble when I click back button ( in this case user might be in product list or some other page of same app) how do we remove the bubble? I can only know package names of app right... but I cannot know if it is product detail page...

Comment: You can detect the listview or some other pattern in the screen prior to Product Detail Page.

Comment: But the screens prior to product detail page are not same....  because user may navigate from home page /  recent suggestions page / product list page / search page etc...  And for different apps it is different so i think it is not a feasible idea to code for each and every specific scenario right.....

Comment: Right! That's why i had put a check on launcher event.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127722/discussion-between-manikanta-and-umesh-chauhan).

Comment: @UmeshChauhan , Thank you, This answer help me a lot

Comment: @UmeshChauhan Hello can my button scroll with native application ? I can use the native application with out interact the my custom button?

Comment: @UmeshChauhan please see this question for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273620/how-to-added-the-custom-button-on-googlesdevice-native-application-in-android

Comment: @UmeshChauhan Thanks For Edit the question,but have you any update regarding that, I want some more as you done..

Comment: I'll add my anw, shortly

Comment: @UmeshChauhan I'm able to read the window content but I'm facing another problem. Whenever I force close my application and then re-launch it after some time; I see that the Accessibility service is stopped. So everytime I need to go to Settings->Accessibility and then enable the service from there. Any solution for this ?

Comment: The app does not appear in the Settings -> Accessibility. I had to add `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"` in the `<service>` of the manifest.

Comment: FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY is now deprecated any other flag to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

I have made successfully this type of application like voodoo.and get Flipkart product page title, price etc successfully. 
the following method used to get user open product screen.

```
private boolean isOpenFlipkartProductScreen(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        if(nodeInfo.getViewIdResourceName()!=null){
            if(nodeInfo.getViewIdResourceName().equals("com.flipkart.android:id/callout_last_linearlayout")){
                Utils.sPrint("You just open product page : " + nodeInfo.getClass());
                isOpenProductPage = true;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

and following code to used get product title name and price.

```
private String getObtainTitle(AccessibilityNodeInfo sourceInfo){

    if(sourceInfo == null)
        return "";

    AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo = sourceInfo.getParent().getParent();
    if(nodeInfo!=null){
        int i = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        for(int i3=0;i3<nodeInfo.getChildCount();i3++){

            try{
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                    if(nodeInfo.getChild(i3).getViewIdResourceName().equals("com.flipkart.android:id/title_layout")) {
                        i = 0;
                        //   while ( i < nodeInfo.getChild(i).getChildCount()){
                        AccessibilityNodeInfo child = nodeInfo.getChild(i3).getChild(i);
                        String charSequence = child.getText().toString();
                        //   Utils.sPrint("Title is : " + charSequence);
                        if(charSequence!=null){
                            return  charSequence;
                        }
                        // }

                    }
                }
               /*
               *
               * Below code to used for getProduct prise in flipkart app product
               *
               * */
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                    if(nodeInfo.getChild(i3).getViewIdResourceName().equals("com.flipkart.android:id/price_layout")){
                        AccessibilityNodeInfo child = nodeInfo.getChild(i3).getChild(i);
                        String charSequence = child.getText().toString();

                        if (child.getText().toString().toUpperCase().startsWith("RS.") ||
                                child.getText().toString().toUpperCase().startsWith("\u20b9")) {
                            String replace = charSequence.replace("Rs.",
                                    "").replace("\u20b9", "");

                            //return replace
                            //   Utils.sPrint("Prise is : " + replace);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception ex){
              //  Utils.sPrint("Ex : " + ex.getMessage());
                return "";
            }

        }
    }
    return "";
}
```