# How read text from a widget on Android?

Tags: android, accessibility

I need read a text from widget owned by another application. It is information about my bank account, the bank application displays it in a widget and I'd like to get the information.

I hope that it is possible using accessibility but I have no idea how to do it.

The application is only for my private issue so I don't care about possible manual steps when I run it first time. The application won't go to Play so it can break some Google rules about usage accessibility functions.
[image]

Comment: Is that widget situated on launcher screen or inside the application? Please notify me on commenting

Comment: @daksh-agrawal it is on launcher.

Comment: I think this can help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35842762/how-to-read-window-content-using-accessibilityservice-and-evoking-ui-using-dr